# Where are the format specifiers implemented/defined in the C language?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

I have been working in C for a couple months now and it has never come to my mind to check where actually the format specifiers implemented/defined in the C language format specifiers like:

```
%f
%d
%p
%s
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("%f",7.8);
}
```

I know these format specifiers are meant to be used with `stdio.h` but my question is where are they implemented/defined in C?

Comment: Behold: [Documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: Have you tried looking in the file `stdio.h`?

Comment: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c

Comment: @klutt They wouldn't be in the header file, they'd be in the source code of `printf()`.

Comment: yes i looked i didn't fine them there

Comment: @tadman documented != implemented

Comment: @Barmar Each compiler will have their own documentation, naturally. That site is good enough to include references to the standards where applicable.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I realized that right when you wrote :)

Comment: The location is not specified in the standard. It depends on your compiler.

Comment: @tadman That still doesn't get you to the code that implements it.

Comment: any final answer ?

Comment: They are implemented as part of the functions that consume them (`printf` and `scanf` variants).

Comment: The behaviour of `printf()` is usually more fully defined under `fprintf()` for example C18 7.21.6.1 describes the format specifiers. The `printf()` function is identical to the `fprintf()` function but input is from `stdin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where are the format specifiers implemented

They are implemented in the specific implementation source code of `printf` you are using. There are many implementations of prinf and implmentation of C standard library - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library#Implementations. You are using *one* of them.

Some are easier to read - https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/stdio/vfprintf.c#L1220 . Some are very hard to comprehend and have been optimized through decades - https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c#L293 .

> defined in the c language?

`printf` format specifiers are "defined" - standardized, specified - in the C language standard. The draft of the standard we are using online you can read about them here [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p1) . But cppreference https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf is friendlier and much better formatted to read than dry standard.